# gradle junit tests logging with slf4j

Tags: java, logging, gradle, junit, slf4j

I am trying to enable test logging with Gradle 4.2.1 and JUnit 4.

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/allow-slf4j-logging-during-junit-tests/24449

For some reason I can only see the INFO log levels and not above (WARN, ERROR). Anyone managed to set this to show all log levels during unit tests?

Thanks in advance.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.21'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version:  '1.1.7'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

...

```
test {
    testLogging {    
        showStandardStreams true
        exceptionFormat 'full'
```

logback-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="io.effectus.cqrs" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: How does your logback(-test).xml look like? I am able to see WARN and ERROR,

Comment: edited question above. any other files I need to make this work? Can you share your setup?

Comment: My setup consisted only of the root logger with the level `INFO` and `logback-test.xml` placed in  `src/test/resources` , make sure your config file is in the classpath and is effectively used.

Comment: I only see the INFO logs so somthing is not working correctly. did you add any gradle links to the file in your build.gradle file?

Comment: Nothing at all, I have the same test config as yours `test {
    testLogging {    
        showStandardStreams true
        exceptionFormat 'full'
    }
}` it worked with `test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}` as well.

Comment: OK, I have some typos, it works now! I did upgrade to latest logback v 1.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two SLF4J implementations on the classpath:

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.21'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version:  '1.1.7'
```

The default for slf4j-simple is only INFO and above, this can be changed by configuring simplelogger.properties which you probably don't have.

So your issue, only seeing INFO and above, is probably caused by slf4j-simple taking precedence over logback-classic.

You mentioned in a comment that it works after upgrading to logback 1.2.3.  Probably for some reason this takes preference over slf4j-simple now, but it's best to make sure you only have a single binding on the classpath.